# How can i copy bundle file to document directory in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have json file in my bundle. I want to copy file to document directory.

```
   var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/data.json';

 RNFS.copyFile(`${RNFS.MainBundlePath}/assests/resource/data.json`, path)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('FILE COPIED');

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });



The file “data.json” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`copyFile` function does not work on Android when copying from app bundle. Instead, you should use the [copyFileAssets](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#copyfileassetsfilepath-string-destpath-string-promisevoid) function.

Additionally, be aware that `RNFS.MainBundlePath` will not provide the correct relative path on Android.

Below is an extended version of the copyFile function that facilitates copying files from the bundle on both iOS and Android platforms:

```
const cpassets = (source: string, destination: string): Promise<void> => 
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? RNFS.copyFile(`${RNFS.MainBundlePath}/${source}`, destination)
    : RNFS.copyFileAssets(source, destination);
```

Using the above function, if you have a file located at `android/app/src/main/assets/data.json`, you can copy it to the documents directory with the following command:

```
await cpassets('data.json', 'cache')
```

This will place the `data.json` file into `/data/user/0/my.app.bundle/files/cache/data.json`

For iOS, the function call remains the same. However, the method for placing your data file into the app bundle differs. You can refer to Apple's documentation on [managing files and folders in your Xcode project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-files-and-folders-in-your-xcode-project#Add-existing-files-and-folders-to-a-project) for more details. Remember to select the appropriate app target when adding the file.